# Is there a way to have :first-child regardless of nesting?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some HTML where I would like just the first `h1` anywhere within `.main` to have specific styling. The first `h1` might not be directly under `.main` and other `h1`s could be anywhere further down with any level of nesting.

The example code shows a few possible HTML structures, but it could be anything.

EDIT: I am wondering if there is a generic solution that excludes other `h1`s from the `:first-child` styling, rather than creating additional rules to "remove" the styling from the `:first-child` rule. Other `h1`s are not necessarily nested with `divs` and the css will need to work for many different HTML structures. The example below is a specific and very simplified version of what might be produced in real life. I have added some other example HTML structures in the code.

```css
h1 {
  color: black;
}
.main h1:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <h1>First h1 - goal is to be red</h1>
  <h1>Second h1 - goal is to be black</h1>
  <div>
    <h1>Third h1 - goal is to be black</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class='main'>
  <div>
    <h1>First h1 - goal is to be red</h1>
    <h1>Second h1 - goal is to be black</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Third h1 - goal is to be black</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class='main'>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>First h1 - goal is to be red</h1>
      </div>
      <h1>Second h1 - goal is to be black</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <h1>Third h1 - goal is to be black</h1>
  
</div>
<hr>
<div class='main'>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>First h1 - goal is to be red</h1>
      </div>
      <h1>Second h1 - goal is to be black</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h1>Third h1 - goal is to be black</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Basically, No there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```css
h1 {
  color: black;
}
#main h1:first-child {
  color: red;
}
#main div h1:first-child {
color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <h1>First Child - goal is to be red</h1>
  <h1>Second Child - goal is to be black</h1>
  <div>
    <h1>Subdiv first child - goal is to be black</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's too specific. The other `h1`s wouldn't necessarily be within divs, plus I want the other `h1`s to be excluded from the styling rule, not to have to specify their styling explicitly. I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: I don't think `#main * h1:first-child` and using `inherit` would help either, as I do not have knowledge of what the styling rules will be beforehand to determine what would need to be inherited (plus it would be potentially different for each HTML block)

Comment: Finally, the first `h1` is not necessarily directly under `#main`, it might also be contained within a `div` or other element.

Comment: (I changed the example code from `#main` to `.main` to allow more HTML structures to be added in the question.)